# .Net Application Loader's Command Line Parser

Tags: c#, .net

I was recently working on a generic parser and gotten to the point of folding (`[...] / {...}`) management I was interested to know how the .Net `args` parser works (The parser that is essentially populating the `args` array in the application entry point).

I started looking around the `CLR` (`mscorlib.dll`) but didn't find what is was looking for, so my question is what mechanism is used to parse these arguments, if it's a CLR Type which one it is, or if it's an un-managed P/Invoke call where it's being declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft recently released the source code of the [.NET Compiler Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn), so we can just take a look!

It contains a class `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLineParser` with a `SplitCommandLineIntoArguments` method, which is described as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Split a command line by the same rules as Main would get the commands.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Rules for command line parsing, according to MSDN:
/// ...
/// </remarks>
```

So here's a complete C# implementation of the `args` parser, conveniently available under the Apache License:

- http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/NonPortable/CommandLine/CommonCommandLineParser.cs

Comment: Great answer, although not quite what I was asking for but exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Call Stack inside the `main` function of a Console application:

```
Program.Main(string[] args = {string[0]}) Line 18 + 0x5 bytes   C#
mscoreei.dll!6f79f5a3()     
mscoree.dll!70bc7f16()  
mscoree.dll!70bc4de3()  
kernel32.dll!76f03677()     
ntdll.dll!77c09d72()    
ntdll.dll!77c09d45()
```

At least `main(string[])` is directly called from the native code. 
I'm still not sure that the parsing also took place inside the native code, maybe it is a managed function and it was called before `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework probably calls into the Windows API.

There are the functions: GetCommandLine (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156.aspx) and CommandLineToArgvW (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647232.aspx) which can be used to get and parse the command line.